# Under what circumstances is there any real security benefit in verifying public keys in signal or WhatsApp?

Tags: encryption, public-key-infrastructure, key-exchange, whatsapp

Encryption is good, sure. But disclosures have revealed that both iOS and Android are so owned by intelligence services that endpoint security on all supported platforms is a joke, anyway. What protection does public key verification afford? Who would have the social positioning to perform a man in the middle that doesn't already own the endpoints inside-out?

Comment: "Disclosures have revealed that both iOS and Android are so owned by intelligence services" -  Citation needed.

Comment: J.Doe - this is going to be entirely subjective, opinion based, and lacking in facts, unless you have a citation, as Iain asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technology and security are implemented in ***layers***. You cannot expect any one layer to be the magic silver bullet to protect everything.

PKI protects the transmission, not the endpoint. It doesn't need to do anything else.

You assume that MitM requires massive resources. What about free wifi? The owner of the router can see everything you send if it was not encrypted. PKI protects you at that layer.

Answer (score 0):

> iOS and Android are so owned by intelligence services that endpoint security on all supported platforms is a joke

Older versions sure. Up to date systems? Do you have any evidence of routine access to application storage/memory on fully up to date devices? There is also the legal aspect - its a lot easier to capture data legally on the wire than it is to hijack a device.

> is there any real security benefit in verifying public keys in signal or WhatsApp?

As long as you do not believe the senders private key to be compromised then yes. It proves the message was sent by them.

Comment: I dont know, man. I know that personally, obtaining media legally entails a lot more time energy money red tape, etc, than just getting it from BitTorrent. Many concur with this. Why would the same principles not apply to Intel services? On up to date systems, what is the going (black) market rate for zero day vulnerabilities? This is a week studied and discussed thing, though I don't stay up with the discussion. However, I don't believe the state of affairs would have gotten any less appalling since I was last appalled by it via reputable, sound sources.

Comment: If security services had ready backdoors into personal devices then why was there such commotion about Syed Farooks iPhone? And although they eventually did get in it was on an older model with several suspected weaknesses which have since been fixed.
Coming back to your original question lets look at it this way. If you believe security services *may* have access checking keys means you may or may not be secure. Not checking them means you definitely aren't secure.